# Exclude class file from being instrumented by Jacoco in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

For Jacoco in Android Gradle build, how to exclude certain class files or library from being instrumented? This is different from excluding class from coverage report generation.

This is due to an opened issue where Jacoco generates an invalid class bytecode that leads to crash at runtime due to verification error: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247699839

Thanks,

I've tried the below without success

```
android { 
    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
                jacoco.excludes = ['some.class.*']
            }
        }
    }
}
```